# Different behaviour for leaf nodes cytoscape

Tags: javascript, html, tree, cytoscape.js

[What the output should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vepuK.png)
I need to create specific trees (phylogenetic trees) with cytoscape.js for my bachelor thesis and for these it would be beneficial to color inner nodes different than child nodes (or leaf nodes = Nodes not having any descendent, see picture). I am a complete newbie in html, so please keep that in mind when answering. I took a look at the manual of Cytoscape but could not find a solution.
Picking the nodes by using

```
cy.nodes(':child').not(':parent');
```

somehow did not work. Thanks a lot in advance for an answer!

EDIT: It worked in klay now but the visualisation is not perfect, I would like to get something looking like in the picture.

Comment: Do you mean leaves (nodes with no successors) or inner nodes (nodes within a parent node compound nodes) or something else. You mentioned three different types of nodes in your question: [leaves](https://js.cytoscape.org/#nodes.leaves), [inner ?= compound](https://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/compound-nodes) and child nodes

Comment: With leaves and child nodes I meant nodes, not having any outgoing edge/ no descendants. These nodes should be marked different than all nodes that are present as parents of these nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the built in function [`cy.nodes().leaves().addClass(...)`](https://js.cytoscape.org/#nodes.leaves), where ... is a class in your stylesheet defining the desired css.

**Edit**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById("cy"),

    // demo your layout
    layout: {
      name: "klay"

      // some more options here...
    },

    style: [{
        selector: "node",
        style: {
          "background-color": "#dd4de2"
        }
      },
      {
        selector: ".leaf",
        style: {
          "background-color": "#000"
        }
      },
      {
        selector: "edge",
        style: {
          "curve-style": "bezier",
          "target-arrow-shape": "triangle",
          "line-color": "#dd4de2",
          "target-arrow-color": "#dd4de2",
          opacity: 0.5
        }
      }
    ],
    elements: {
      nodes: [{
          data: {
            id: "n0"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n1"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n2"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n3"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n4"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n5"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n6"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n7"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n8"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n9"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n10"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n11"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n12"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n13"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n14"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: "n15"
          }
        }
      ],
      edges: [{
          data: {
            source: "n0",
            target: "n1"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n1",
            target: "n2"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n1",
            target: "n3"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n2",
            target: "n4"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n4",
            target: "n5"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n4",
            target: "n6"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n6",
            target: "n7"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n6",
            target: "n8"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n8",
            target: "n9"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n8",
            target: "n10"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n10",
            target: "n11"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n11",
            target: "n12"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n12",
            target: "n13"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n13",
            target: "n14"
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: "n13",
            target: "n15"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }));

  cy.nodes().leaves().addClass("leaf");
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, liberation sans, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#cy {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/klayjs@0.4.1/klay.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-klay@3.1.3/cytoscape-klay.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I added the selector leafs above the selector of nodes and edges in the var cy style location and after the var cy description is done, I added cy.nodes().leaves().addClass(leafs), but still all nodes have the color which I declared in the css for the nodes. ``` style: [
        {
          selector: 'leafs',
          css: {
            'background-color': 'black',
            'border-color': 'black',
          }
        }, ... ] ``` is how my styles in the var cy look like, I hope you understand the prolblem, thank you so much for answering in the first place @Stephan T.!

Comment: I will add a snippet for you to understand the solution

Comment: Thats brilliant, it worked for the klay demo, I was working with dagre, this might be the problem. Do you know if dagre provides the same feature?

Comment: Yes it does, you just have to copy the relevant lines. Did you use the class operator in your selector? In your comment you had 'leaves' instead of '.leaves'. Otherwise just post your code in the question and I can edit the answer according to that

Comment: It now worked with dagre as well. The code helped me a lot. The problem might have been the missing dot at the selector. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You can always just post your code the way i did (if you click on edit, you have the option to edit the snippet, that way you see how it is done here on Stackoverflow).  It helps a lot to have a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as a starting point, you will get better results that way. Glad I could help!

Comment: Hi @Stephan T., maybe you can also answer my other question:) I tried to do a snippet which can be run but unfortunately it is only normal code that I posted. But maybe you know an answer. Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62703987/cytoscape-change-length-of-second-axis-taxi-branch