# cytoscape: change length of second axis taxi branch

Tags: html, tree, cytoscape.js

I want to create a tree with different branch lengths, looking like this:[image: looking like this]
Is there a possibility of assigning a length to the secondary axis of taxi trees? I tried to assigning a weight to a branch, but every branch has the same length in the x-asis.
In the following you can see my code, maybe you see an error or can help me with this problem. Thank you!
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
var toJson = function(res){ return res.Json(); };

```
var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
container: document.getElementById("cy"),

// demo your layout
layout: {
  name: "dagre",
  rankDir: 'LR'

  // some more options here...
},

style: [{
    selector: "node",
    style: {
      //"background-color": "#dd4de2",
      'background-color': '#9dbaea',
      'border-color': 'white',
      'border-style': 'solid',
      'border-width': 0.3,
      'text-valign': 'center',
      'text-halign': 'right',
      'height': 5,
      'width': 5,
      'font-size': 3,
    }
  },
  {
    selector: ".leaf",
    style: {
      "background-color": "red",
      'content': 'data(id)',
      'font-size': 6,
      'height': 5,
      'width': 5,
    }
  },
  {
    selector: ".root",
    style: {
      "background-color": "#9dbaea",
      'font-size': 4,
      'content': "root",
      'height': 5,
      'width': 5,
    }
  },
  {
    selector: "edge",
    style: {
      'width': 1,
      'length': 'data(weight)',
      //'target-arrow-shape': 'vee',
      'line-color': 'black',
      //'target-arrow-color': '#9dbaea',
      'curve-style': 'taxi',
      //needs to be updated depending no edgeweight
      'taxi-turn': '100px',
      'taxi-direction': 'vertical',
      'edge-distances': 'node-position',
      opacity: 0.7
    }
  }
],
elements: {
  nodes: [
      { data: { id: 'inner_n0', type: 'taxi' } },
      { data: { id: 'inner_n1', type: 'taxi' } },
      { data: { id: 'inner_n2', type: 'taxi' } },
      { data: { id: 'inner_n3', type: 'taxi' } },
      { data: { id: 'cell1' } },
      { data: { id: 'cell2' } },
      { data: { id: 'cell3' } },
      { data: { id: 'cell4' } },
      { data: { id: 'cell5' } },
    ],
    edges: [
      { data: { source: 'inner_n0', weight:'10', target: 'inner_n1' }, "classes": 'taxi'  },
      { data: { source: 'inner_n0', weight:'10', target: 'inner_n3' }, "classes": 'taxi'  },
      { data: { source: 'inner_n1', weight:'10', target: 'inner_n2' }, "classes": 'taxi'  },
      { data: { source: 'inner_n1', weight:'10', target: 'cell2' }, "classes": 'taxi'  },
      { data: { source: 'inner_n2', weight:'5', target: 'cell3' }, "classes": 'taxi'  },
      { data: { source: 'inner_n3', weight:'5', target: 'cell1' }, "classes": 'taxi'  },
      { data: { source: 'inner_n3', weight:'20', target: 'cell5' }, "classes": 'taxi'  },
      { data: { source: 'inner_n2', weight:'10', target: 'cell4' }, "classes": 'taxi'  }
    ]
}

//elements: fetch('input.json').then(toJson),
}));

cy.nodes().leaves().addClass("leaf");
cy.nodes().roots().addClass("root");
});
```

```
    <!doctype html>

<html>

  <head>
    <title>phylogenetic tree</title>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/browse/dagre@0.8.5/dist/dagre.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre/1.5.0/cytoscape-dagre.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-klay@3.1.3/cytoscape-klay.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      body {
        font-family: helvetica;
        font-size: 14px;
      }

      #cy {
        width: 950px;
        height: 650px;
        border-style: double;
        border-color: coral;
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 999;
      }


      h1 {
        opacity: 0.5;
        font-size: 1em;
      }
    </style>

    <script src="code.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>cytoscape-dagre demo</h1>

    <div id="cy"></div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This might be helpful: [Documentation Request: How to Control Edge Length](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/1514)

Comment: As far as I understand this, there is not a real way of solving my problem. The only way would be to calculate coordinates for every node which could be pretty difficult for a big graph.

Comment: Basically, yes. Seems a bit weird, the edge length is a pretty important part of a layout. A mapper would be nice for this. But I don't think, that it is currently possible with cytoscape.js. Maybe someone else knows more about this though?